# Overwrote my entire repo in Git and I can't seem to get back to my previous commits

Tags: git, github, repository

I messed up some files locally and pushed those to my repo, and wanted to go back to an older version when I realized my mistake. I did some searching and found a similar question here, so I followed the answer and did the following:

```
git log
git reset --hard <hash>
git push -f origin master
```

Now, I am using github for my University and earlier I had pulled the solutions to an old assignment from the Professors repo. I am guessing I chose the Professors solution hash, when I ran `git reset --hard` because my repo now says it is authored by the professor, it has all of the old solution files, and none of my own files. Everything was replaced locally as well, and `git log` only shows commits to the solutions repo by the Professor. Is there any way I can get back *my* previous commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git reflog` to go back before a hard reset.

Running `git reflog` will yield something like this:

```
f735139 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
a76edca HEAD@{1}: commit: second commit
f735139 HEAD@{2}: commit (initial): initial commit
```

You can check out the commit before the reset like this:

```
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```

You will get a detached head warning, so create a new branch starting before the reset:

```
git checkout -b <new branch name>
```

Now you will have a branch with everything before your hard reset.

If you do want to go back in time in the future, I would create a new branch at the commit you reset to. You could do it this way:

```
git checkout <sha-1 hash of the commit you reset to>
git checkout -b <new branch name>
```

This way you leave your master branch alone and have a new branch at an earlier point.

---

EDIT: Since you want to merge changes that undo a pushed reset into master, I would advise merging the remote changes and discarding them. Try this:

```
git fetch origin master
git merge FETCH_HEAD -s ours
```

You should be able to push after that.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But how can I show the commits in my master branch? Right now they are in the newly created branch.

Comment: @Amru you can merge your new branch into master and push that. It's best to avoid resets and such on commits that have already been pushed elsewhere. If possible, do those operations on your local repository and push the end result.

Comment: I did `git checkout master` followed by `git merge newbranch` and now when I push master, I get this error:  `! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:abcd-fall2013-cs123/amrue.git' To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.` but I don't want to pull remote changes because there are similar file names, and I don't want them to overwrite my files.

Comment: @Amru I think the best thing to do is pull the changes and discard them. I edited my answer with how to do that.

Comment: What I ended up doing is using `git push origin +master` from another answer. There is only one other person touching the repo so it shouldn't be too bad. Thanks for everything! Got everything in working order.